# Backbone collection sortBy multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, group-by

I'm working on web app where I have to show data in specific way. I have my views organized like:

**ItemsView**

```
    render: function(){
      for(var i=0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
        this.renderItem(this.collection.models[i]); 
      }
      return this;

    },
    renderItem: function( model ){
      // here I'm creating new ItemView for every model in collection
      var itemView = new ItemView({ model: model }); 
      itemView.render();
      jBone(this.el).append(itemView.el);
    }
```

**ItemView**

```
    render: function () {
      var model = this.model.toJSON();
      this.el.innerHTML += '<p>'+model.title+'</p><div>'+model.volume+'</div>';
      return this;
    },
```

Now I have data rendered like this:

```
 Title 1 | Volume 1 
 Title 1 | Volume 1 
 Title 2 | Volume 50
 Title 2 | Volume 50 
 Title 2 | Volume 20 
 Title 2 | Volume 1 
 Title 3 | Volume 1
```

What I want is to render my data like with groupBy title and volume then I will see quantity of same items:

```
_________|__________|___count___
 Title 1 | Volume 1 |    2
 Title 2 | Volume 50|    2
 Title 2 | Volume 20|    1
 Title 2 | Volume 1 |    1
 Title 3 | Volume 1 |    1
```

I'm able to do something like this in DB layer like:

```
select title, volume, Count(*)
from items
group by title, volume
```

But then I don't have any id or something with I'm able to work in frontend layer (When I receive socket I'm not able to indentify changed item). So probably I have to groupBy items in client side? Also I'm not able to add quantity column into database...

Is there possible solution  at all?

Thanks a lot for any opinion

Comment: One option: https://jsfiddle.net/mbgdewxz/

Comment: @Vohuman thanks a lot! Is also possible to include IDs of included items? I mean like another object in array `{Title: 2,Volume: 50,count: 3, ids: [1,22,32]}` Also I can use length of ids object as "quantity". You can also create it like answer...

Comment: You are very welcome! Yes, why not: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2pewz5/. Please note that this solution adds 2 properties to some of the array's objects, i.e. it modifies the original object. If this is not what you want you can return a new object instead of returning the first object (in the `map` handler). https://jsfiddle.net/228ddsov/

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
var res = _.chain(col).groupBy(function (el) {
    return [el.title, el.volume];
}).map(function(el) {
    var ret = {};
    ret.volume = el[0].volume;
    ret.title  = el[0].title;
    ret.ids    = _.pluck(el, 'id');
    return ret;
}).value();
```

update: As @muistooshort's example shows the above solution can be problematic in some cases. Another option is using the `reduce` method:

```
var exl = [];
var res = col.reduce(function (ret, el) {
    if (_.contains(exl, el.id)) {
        return ret;
    }
    var f = _.filter(col, function (ent) {
        return ent.title === el.title && ent.volume === el.volume;
    });
    var ids = _.pluck(f, 'id');
    exl = exl.concat(ids);
    ret.push({
        title: el.title,
        volume: el.volume,
        count: f.length,
        ids: ids
    });
   return ret; 
}, []);
```

Comment: Do you say that as the string representation of the returned arrays is used as keys? It shouldn't make any problems.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem, there are holes and unstated assumptions: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nvxqbu34/

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for your opinion. Do you have any idea how to do it right? Thanks a lot

Comment: @muistooshort You are right, I missed _that_ case. Thanks.

Comment: You could probably get away with manually joining the array elements using a `"\0"` delimiter. Not 100% solid but should only break with the most bizarre and pathological inputs.